DS-160 - B1/B2 - Work & Education - I work full time & study part time - F-1 refused earlier
a bit of a confusion while filling DS-160 for my B1/B2.
I am a full-time software engineer at a b2b logistics software company and I have been working as a software engineer for 2 years now. This is my second work place.
I never got a degree in CS and just last year started studying part-time at a local university affiliated with a one in the UK and accredited by BCS.
I study part-time and work-full time. Both are serious and important but since I am working full time, I added that as my "primary".
However, in the section where they ask:

Have you attended any educational institutions at a secondary level or above?

I am not able to add the "Attendance to" date in the future. < This is the problem.
Adding education is especially important to me because last year before starting my degree program, I applied for a F-1 and was planning to study there. However, that got refused for whatever reason and there, with my genuine interest of studying, started my bachelors degree here and I think showing that will be important in this case as I had my F-1 rejected.
This visit is important to me as I am attending the wedding of a family member.

Did you get a solution for this?
